# Alert Message close button

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, fonts

I am trying to have an alert message (how to play a game) pop up when the site loads, and have an "x" button to close it. The funny thing is, the button is visible when the font-family is something else like "Courier" etc., but my game is Harry Potter themed and I want to use a special font, which always seems to somehow "hide" the button. I want to know if there's a way to use the "HarryPotter7" font and also have my "x" button show up. Any help would really be appreciated!

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  color: #6e2c60;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Harry P';
  src: url('http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/harry-p.TTF');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'HarryPotter7';
  src: url('http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/harrypotter7.ttf');
}
```

```html
   <style>
      .alert 
      {
        font-family: "HarryPotter7"; 
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52);
        color: purple;
      }

      .closebtn 
      {
        margin-left: 15px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .closebtn:hover 
      {
        color: red;
      }
  </style>
  
 <body>   
   <div class="alert">
      <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
      <strong style="font-size: 150%">How to Play:</strong> 
      <br> ✥ Type the full name and then hit enter or click on the "CHECK" button.
      <br> ✥ The system is case insensitive, but the spelling must be right! Start and pause the timer as you want, or reset the entire game with the reset button. 
      <br> ✥ If time is up, the page will automatically reload to the scores page, or, you can click on "Finish Game" button towards the bottom.
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace "&times ;" to "x"

`<span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">x</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use an `×` or an icon if you choose to.

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  color: #6e2c60;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Harry P';
  src: url('http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/harry-p.TTF');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'HarryPotter7';
  src: url('http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/harrypotter7.ttf');
}
```

```html
   <style>
      .alert 
      {
        font-family: "HarryPotter7"; 
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52);
        color: purple;
      }

      .closebtn 
      {
        margin-left: 15px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .closebtn:hover 
      {
        color: red;
      }
  </style>
  
 <body>   
   <div class="alert">
      <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">× </span> 
      <strong style="font-size: 150%">How to Play:</strong> 
      <br> ✥ Type the full name and then hit enter or click on the "CHECK" button.
      <br> ✥ The system is case insensitive, but the spelling must be right! Start and pause the timer as you want, or reset the entire game with the reset button. 
      <br> ✥ If time is up, the page will automatically reload to the scores page, or, you can click on "Finish Game" button towards the bottom.
    </div>
  </body>
```